# Tail of a divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that if a series converges, its tail tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. But in the case of a divergent series, what can we conclude about its  tail's limit?

Comment: Nothing. The infinite term can still go to zero, as is the case with the Harmonic series (which is divergent) . But it can also approach a different value, in which the Series is divergent. In other words, if the infinite term (tail's end) goes to zero, the sum of the series is "inconclusive"

Comment: Agreed. Even $\int \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} $ diverges despite the fact that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x^{1/2}} = 0 $.

Comment: The usual meaning of a tail is a sum $\sum_N^\infty a_i$,  where $N$ is informally thought of as "large."  Under that interpretation, the tail goes to $0$ iff the series converges.